# Which "space-time coincidences" are described by a "co-ordinate system in which the gravitational field does not appear"?

Tags: relativity, foundations

In Einstein's exposition of the foundations of General Relativity (cmp. http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Foundation_of_the_Generalised_Theory_of_Relativity , end of §3) there appears an emphasis on considerations of "*coincidences*":

> *All our well-substantiated space-time propositions amount to the determination of space-time coincidences. [...] The results of our measurements are nothing else than well-proved theorems about such coincidences of material points*

and their relation to "*co-ordinates*":

> *The introduction of a system of co-ordinates serves no other purpose than an easy description of totality of such coincidences.*

Subsequently (in §4) one more or less specific "*system of co-ordinates*" is suggested:

> The nature of acceleration of an infinitely small (positional) co-ordinate system is hereby to be so chosen, that the gravitational field does not appear; this is possible for an infinitely small region. $X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}$ are the spatial co-ordinates; [...]

Question:
What, explicitly, is contained in the corresponding "*totality of such coincidences*";
or in some specific subset of this "*totality*"?,
of which the indicated "*co-ordinate system in which the gravitational field does not appear*" is a suitably "*easy description*".

Does this "*totality*" contain, for instance:

(1)
for any three distinct "*material points*" (${\textbf A}$, ${\textbf B}$, and ${\textbf P}$, who are assigned the corresponding unequal constant "*spatial co-ordinate*" triples $\{ \, X_{1}^{\textbf A}, X_{2}^{\textbf A}, X_{3}^{\textbf A} \, \}$, $\{ \, X_{1}^{\textbf B}, X_{2}^{\textbf B}, X_{3}^{\textbf B} \, \}$, and $\{ \, X_{1}^{\textbf P}, X_{2}^{\textbf P}, X_{3}^{\textbf P} \, \}$, respectively),
and for any "*coincidence*" ${\textbf A}_{\mathscr X}$ in which ${\textbf A}$ had been participating,
the "*coincidence*" that

${\textbf A}\!$'s indication of having seen that ${\textbf P}$ saw ${\textbf A}\!$'s indication of having seen that ${\textbf B}$ saw "*coincidence*" ${\textbf A}_{\mathscr X}$
was coincident to
${\textbf A}\!$'s indication of having seen that ${\textbf B}$ saw ${\textbf A}\!$'s indication of having seen that ${\textbf P}$ saw "*coincidence*" ${\textbf A}_{\mathscr X}$
?

And is "*an easy description*" of this "*totality*" afforded by the indicated system for instance in the sense that:

(2)
for any two distinct "*material points*" (${\textbf A}$ and ${\textbf B}$, who are assigned the corresponding unequal constant "*spatial co-ordinate*" triples $\{ \, X_{1}^{\textbf A}, X_{2}^{\textbf A}, X_{3}^{\textbf A} \, \}$, and $\{ \, X_{1}^{\textbf B}, X_{2}^{\textbf B}, X_{3}^{\textbf B} \, \}$, respectively)
there is another triple, $\{ \, X_{1}^{\textbf M}, X_{2}^{\textbf M}, X_{3}^{\textbf M} \, \}$, reserved as constant "*spatial co-ordinates*" to denote a "*material point*" ${\textbf M}$, if it happens to exist, as "middle between ${\textbf A}$ and ${\textbf B}$", described by the "*coincidences*"

- that for any "*coincidence*" ${\textbf A}_{\mathscr X}$ in which ${\textbf A}$ had been participating,

${\textbf A\!}$'s indication of having seen that ${\textbf M}$ saw ${\textbf A\!}$'s indication of having seen that ${\textbf M}$ saw "*coincidence*" ${\textbf A}_{\mathscr X}$
was coincident to
${\textbf A\!}$'s indication of having seen that ${\textbf B}$ saw  "*coincidence*" ${\textbf A}_{\mathscr X}$, and

- that for any "*coincidence*" ${\textbf B}_{\mathscr Y}$ in which ${\textbf B}$ had been participating,

${\textbf B}$'s indication of having seen that ${\textbf M}$ saw ${\textbf B}$'s indication of having seen that ${\textbf M}$ saw "*coincidence*" ${\textbf B}_{\mathscr Y}$
was coincident to
${\textbf B}$'s indication of having seen that ${\textbf A}$ saw  "*coincidence*" ${\textbf B}_{\mathscr Y}$, and

- that for any "*coincidence*" ${\textbf M}_{\mathscr Z}$ in which ${\textbf M}$ had been participating,

${\textbf M}$'s indication of having seen that ${\textbf A}$ saw "*coincidence*" ${\textbf M}_{\mathscr Z}$
was coincident to
${\textbf M}$'s indication of having seen that ${\textbf B}$ saw  "*coincidence*" ${\textbf M}_{\mathscr Z}$
?

Answer (score 1):

> What, explicitly, is contained in the corresponding "totality of such coincidences";

Basically these coincidences are collisions of particles. We have world-lines of particles, but he's saying that all physical observations reduce to observations of intersections of these world-lines. The world-lines themselves, and the way they lie in the background of spacetime, are not directly observable. This introduction to the paper is giving a physical motivation for describing spacetime using noneuclidean geometry. In the context of geometry, the word "incidence" or "coincidence" has a specific mathematical definition, which is the intersection of two figures. For example, if two planes intersect in a line, this is called an incidence relation between them. "Coincidence" implies nothing more or less than what you'd expect from the root "coincide."

> of which the indicated "co-ordinate system in which the gravitational field does not appear" is a suitably "easy description".

He's saying that locally, we can always choose a frame of reference defined by a free-falling observer. By the equivalence principle, there is no gravitational field detectable by such an observer.

> Does this "totality" contain, for instance: [...]

After this point, it seems to me that you've wandered off track. By "coincidences," he means something very specific: the intersection of two world-lines. It's not an observer's "indication of having seen something."

Comment: "_We have world-lines of particles_" -- We have Einstein's (and my) insistence on _coincidence(s)_. How do we construct the notion "_world-line_" from that?: We may need "identifiability" of participants in order to say that (or ask whether) some same "_particle_" took part in several _coincidences_; and we may even require some notion of "ordering" those. "_It's not an observer's "indication of having seen something."_" -- What about the role of "M" [here (§8)](http://archive.org/details/berdiespezielle00unkngoog)? Aren't _coincidences_ observable (by other participants)?

Comment: contd.: "_a frame of reference defined by a free-falling observer_" -- At least I've managed to ask my question without using (and thus presuming to comprehend) the notion of "_a free-falling observer_"; but rather in the hope to explicate _space time coincidences_ (separately, or in relation to each other) by which to define the notion of "_a free-falling observer_" in the first place. This seems to be in line with the cited quotations, even if it may be ahistorical.

Comment: p.s.: Frank Wappler wrote (1st comment): "_What about the role of "M" here (§8)?_" -- Sorry, this and the underlying link were referring to a chapter in a book written by Einstein originally in German. The corresponding translation can be found for instance [here, instead](http://archive.org/details/relativitythespe00einsuoft). To note (ch. VIII, On the Idea of Time in Physics): "_If the observer [M] perceives the two flashes of lightning at the same time, then [...]_". Doesn't this describe a relevant form of _space-time coincidence_, that Einstein meant, and I used in (1), (2)?

Comment: @user12262: *Aren't coincidences observable (by other participants)?* Yes, but unlike many types of observations they are also observer-independent. *We have Einstein's (and my) insistence on coincidence(s). How do we construct the notion "world-line" from that?* Because Einstein is assuming a certain level of mathematical literacy, according to which incidence relations are understood to be a geometrical notion.

Comment: "_Einstein is assuming a certain level of mathematical literacy_" -- Sure. Is it accordingly understood that Einstein is assuming/permitting any participants in any one "_coincidence_" to be **identified** and that it may be recognized whether someone (who has been identified as participating in one particular "_coincidence_") took part in several "_coincidences_"? (Even though that's admitting a **relation** between several "_coincidences_"; in contrast for instance to the "Footnote" remark seen [here](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/einstein-philscience/)?)

Comment: "_they [coincidences] are also observer-independent._" -- If it is (in Einstein's sense) permissible to identify any "_material point/particle/participant/observer_" who took part in in any one "_coincidence_" and to recognize who took part in several "_coincidences_" then "_coincidences_" are in turn generally distinguishable by the identification of who took part; they are **not** independent of who took part. Find an example again in the book mentioned above: observer M took part in the "_coincidence_" called "perceiving the two flashes", while observer M' (of chapter IX) did not.